# Are iceberg tables compatible with tableau? how to create tableau reports using iceberg tables?

Tags: tableau-api, tableau-desktop, apache-iceberg

I am currently creating an iceberg table and one of the use cases from consumer is to be able to perform reporting using these tables in tableau. Hence I wanted to understand if iceberg format tables are compatible in tableau. please help

I tried to search online if there is straightforward guidelines how to import iceberg tables in tableau but could not understand much from one of the threads which recommended to use dremio.